net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR socket error only when using https
I'm currently making a node.js/express project with socket.io. I have already containerized it with Docker and deployed on Elastic Beanstalk, and successfully connected it with Cloudfront and my personal domain with Route53.
When accessing the application through Beanstalk, everything works fine. However, when I go to my personal site, which uses https, there is a polling error for the socket:

This error only appears when I use https. I can still access the landing page of my application, but I am unable to open anything related to the chat application that uses the socket.
This is my server.js:
const express = require('express');
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const app = express(); // initialize express
const server = http.createServer(app); // HTTP server created
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080 // set port to value received from environment variable or 8080 if null
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "https://chess.adamwu.dev", // Replace with your domain
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "HEAD"],
        credentials: true
    },
    path: '/socket.io'
});

const cors = require('cors');
const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus: 200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Parses JSON bodies
app.use(express.json());
// Serve static files from the react app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/public')));
// all other requests point to the index.html file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/public', 'index.html'));
});

And my socket.js:
import { io } from "socket.io-client"; // import connection function

const socket = io.connect('https://localhost');
export default socket;

I'm guessing it has something to do with my SSL certificate, but the domain name is mine and I have the proper certificate from ACM that I have attached to the load balancer on beanstalk. I am also using the NGINX proxy (through AWS Beanstalk, I have no idea what it does). Also, on my personal domain, it says the connection is secure. If you want to take a look at my site, it is https://chess.adamwu.dev/.
I've tried messing with the frontend by setting rejectUnauthroized to false and secure to true, to no avail. I currently have my listeners on port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS, but for my personal site, I only want to use HTTPS. Note I use port 8080 for the container. I see a lot of posts talking about a cert and key file, but I don't know if I need that for my scenario, since I already have a certificate for my domain on ACM.
